# Telerik AppBuilder : How can we create tab based application using NativeScript

Tags: ios, telerik, hybrid-mobile-app, nativescript

I want to create a tab based application using NativeScript which is having currently 4 tab as shown in image below.

[image: Bottom bar - tab]

Answer (score 3):

You can use `TabView` component. You could also review the [article](https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/ui/tab-view) in NativeScript documentation. I am also attaching sample example.

```
<TabView selectedIndex="0">
  <TabView.items>
    <TabViewItem title="Tab 1">
      <TabViewItem.view>
        <Label text="Label in Tab1" />
       </TabViewItem.view>
     </TabViewItem>
    <TabViewItem title="Tab 2">
      <TabViewItem.view>
        <Label text="Label in Tab2" />
       </TabViewItem.view>
     </TabViewItem>
    <TabViewItem title="Tab 3">
      <TabViewItem.view>
        <Label text="Label in Tab3" />
       </TabViewItem.view>
     </TabViewItem>
   </TabView.items>
 </TabView>
```

for further help you could review the sample example [here](https://github.com/tsonevn/sideDrawer-TabView). In case you would like to create NativeScript Angular2 project you will find appropriate example [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-sdk-examples-ng/tree/master/app/ui/tab-view).

Answer (score 0):

```
    <TabView selectedIndex="0">
  <TabView.items>
    <TabViewItem title="Tab 1">
      <TabViewItem.view>
        <Label text="Label in Tab1" />
       </TabViewItem.view>
     </TabViewItem>
    <TabViewItem title="Tab 2">
      <TabViewItem.view>
        <Label text="Label in Tab2" />
       </TabViewItem.view>
     </TabViewItem>
    <TabViewItem title="Tab 3">
      <TabViewItem.view>
        <Label text="Label in Tab3" />
       </TabViewItem.view>
     </TabViewItem>
   </TabView.items>
 </TabView>
```